# Adding Slide Functionality for Touch Phones

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, touch, swipe

Is there and independent plugin I can use that allows me to add swipe funcitonality from touch devices?

So I have a jQuery plugin but can I simply download an add-on that gives sqipe functionality to an existing plugin?

If not can you tell me the syntax to add it in myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a mousewheel control by simply using "jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4" and adding a couple of lines of code to the waterwheel script. Right under "Event handlers for the optional carousel controls":

```
$(this).bind('mousewheel',this,function(event, delta) {
if (delta > 0) {
rotateCarousel(true,delta);
return false;
}
else
{
rotateCarousel(false,delta);
return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't eplxain properly. I have a carousel plugin; waterwheel caorusel..

And I want to be able to swipe across on an iphone. Can I add this functionality in?

Comment: i have edited my answer, this should work to add a swipe effect for all devices

Comment: let me know how that goes for you

Comment: Hmm Doesn't seem to allow my iphone to slide the box across..

The mousewheel works though...